# How to display relation ship property on the arrow itself in Neo4J?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I created my graph and its working as expected. My relationship table has property **Name**. When I merge my 2 tables (Entity 1 and Entity 2) and connect them Entity ID :

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Rel(12March2021).csv' AS row
WITH toFloat(row.Entity1_ID) AS Entity1Id, toFloat(row.Entity2_ID) AS Entity2Id, row.Name AS Name, row.Label AS Label
MATCH (e1:Entity1 {Entity1Id: Entity1Id})
MATCH (e2:Entity2 {Entity2Id: Entity2Id})
MERGE (e2)-[rel:CONTAINS {Name: Name}]->(e1)
RETURN count(rel);
```

Then to display the graph, I do the following

```
MATCH (e2:Entity2)-[rel:CONTAINS]->(e1:Entity1)
RETURN e1, rel, e2 LIMIT 200;
```

As seen in the image below all relations are labelled **'Contains**' with property **'Name'** I want the value of the propoerty 'Name' to be displayed on the arrows instead of the word 'Contains'. Any idea how can I do that ? , For example in the highlighted arrow below I want the word 'obtain' to replace'Contains', same goes for the other relationship arrows  (Note: I am using Neo4J Browser)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way as you do so for nodes.
Select the relationship type (in my example attached, it is CITY), then select the property to be displayed as a caption (in my example, it is since)
[image]